# recover "DbContext" lost out after a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, methods, dbcontext, iqueryable

I need your help.
I begin to ASP.net and I fail to retrieve a "dbcontext" to display my request in a "datagrid". Here is my code:

```
public IQueryable<DiagTab> Clooper(string m_ValEnvoi)
    {
        string Ladatatable = m_ValEnvoi; 

        using (var db = new DiagEntities()) 
        {
            var secki = db.DiagTabs.Where(Ladatatable); // Ladatatabase = Dynamic LinQ 

            return secki;
        }
```

I call this way (no error)

```
TheLoop pilou = new TheLoop();                                         
                pilou.Clooper(Valtest);
                var olami = pilou.Clooper(Valtest);
```

but if i try this:

```
var selection_click = olami;
                    GridView1.DataSource = selection_click.ToList();
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

the code is interrupted and displays "Could not complete the operation because the DbContext has been deleted".
Is it possible to get the paste has Dbcontext for this request?
thanks for your help

Comment: You aren't materializing the query before disposing `DbContext`. When you actually execute it, it's already been disposed.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `ToList()` inside the method, before disposing the `DbContext`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .
Yes but no. I will use this method several times, and with this approach I will lose this information and code that uses "Dynamic Linq" is no longer used in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `using` which dispose the `DiagEntities` and instead of it, if you want to use it in several methods just declare a property for your `DiagEntities` in the class constructor.

```
public IQueryable<DiagTab> Clooper(string m_ValEnvoi)
    {
        string Ladatatable = m_ValEnvoi; 


            var secki = db.DiagTabs.Where(Ladatatable); // Ladatatabase = Dynamic LinQ 

            return secki;
   }
```